# In WW2, did Germany ever mine Uranium from Czechoslovakia?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, czechoslovakia

1938 Oct 01, Germany begins annexing the Sudentenland. 1939 Mar 15, Germany invaded the rest of Czechoslovakia.

There is a mine, far on the western border, called the Joachimsthal Mine.

[image]

Today it is called [Jáchymov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A1chymov), but back then was known as Joachimsthal. This place had a silver mine dating back to the 1500's. **It also produced Uranium.** In fact, when Martin Klaproth first identified Uranium in 1789, I believe that Uranium came from the mine in Czechoslovakia.

I would like to know if Germany, at any point from 1938 to 1945, mined Uranium from this mine. If so, how much, and what concentration of Uranium did it have.

I'm aware that Germany never had a serious atomic bomb project comparable to the Manhattan Project. I would nevertheless like to know if they ever tried to mine Uranium from here.

Comment: Two small additions : 1.When Marie Curie discovered radioactivity, she was also working with uranium from Joachimsthal. 2.Surprisingly enough, the silver from Jachymov is also the etymological origin of the word "Dollar" (through Joachimstahl -> Thaller -> Dollar).

Comment: Note it was named Jáchymov (as well as Joachimsthal) even in the 1930s. I have a book in my hand right now with a chapter named "Dobývání radia v Jáchymově" = "Radium mining in Jáchymov". During the war it was annexed by Germany and obviously named in German only. So it is not as in the close Falkenau/Falknov which was renamed to Sokolov only after the war.

Comment: [This note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_submarine_U-234) on the attempted shipment of Uranium from Germany to Japan in 1945 may be of interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Apparently, yes.**

---

[This site](http://uran-deutsch-tschechischer-erinnerungsort.info/?page_id=173) states (translation mine):

> Während des Zweiten Weltkriegs, St. Joachimsthal war damals Teil des ans Deutsche Reich angeschlossenen Sudetenlands, wurde in den Gruben Uran für Forschungszwecke der deutschen Wehrmacht abgebaut.

"During World War II, St. Joachimsthal being part of the Sudetenland incorporated into the German Reich back then, Uranium was mined for research purposes for the German Wehrmacht."

The website was produced by the [German-Czech Textbook Commission](http://www.gei.de/en/departments/europe-narratives-images-spaces/europe-and-the-national-factor/german-czech-textbook-commission.html).

---

[This site](https://ome-lexikon.uni-oldenburg.de/orte/sankt-joachimsthal-jachymov/) states (translation mine):

> Im Zuge der Umsetzung des 1941 erarbeiteten "Göring-Programms" wurden zuerst französische, später sowjetische Kriegsgefangene in den Minen von Sankt Joachimsthal eingesetzt.

"In the course of implementing the 'Göring program' compiled in 1941, first French, later Soviet POW's were employed in the Sankt Joachimsthal mines."

The website was produced by the [University of Oldenburg](https://ome-lexikon.uni-oldenburg.de/web-impressum/).

---

As an update to a question in the comments as to *how much* Uranium was mined, via the German WP article on the [Uranprojekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranprojekt) I found [this Spiegel article](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-46409361.html), translation mine (as much as I loathe citing David Irving for *anything*):

> Auer beutete seit der Einverleibung der Tschechoslowakei im März 1939 die Uranbergwerke in Sankt-Joachimsthal aus, und der Laborleiter Nikolaus Riehl erachtete das Uranprojekt als so vielversprechend, daß er selbst die Leitung der Uran-Produktion übernahm und innerhalb weniger Wochen in Oranienburg einen Betrieb aufbaute, dessen monatliche Produktionskapazität etwa eine Tonne Uranoxyd betrug.

"Since the annexiation of Czechoslovakia in March 1939, Auer [company] exploited the Uranium mines in Sankt-Joachimsthal, and the laboratory supervisor Nikolaus Riehl deemed the Uranprojekt so promising that he himself took control of the Uranium production. Within a few months he did built a factory in Oranienburg capable of producting about one [metric] ton of Uranium oxide per month."

Note that the connection between the Oranienburg factory and the Joachimsthal mines is a rather loose one; the same article also mentions that Germany took hold of 3500 tons of Uranium minerals from the *Union Minere* in Belgium, and that the Auer company used (mainly?) those to satisfy their demands.

Comment: I found a somewhat corroborating source here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olen,_Belgium It says that Olen had a refinery for Uranium Ore (citation), but also says 1200 tonnes were captured by Germany (no citation). However, I suspect the refinery there was for extracting radium rather than concentrating Uranium. They are not necessarily the same thing even when dealing with a Ra-U orebody. Mining is a complicated business. BTW thank you for quoting things in the original language. It seems very few people take care to do that these days.

Comment: Isn't the word "angeschlossenen" related to "anschluss"? (It's been a while since I had German classes in high school.)

Comment: @svick: It is, but I had no better idea on how to translate that into English properly, hence the question mark. (German is my native language, in case it hasn't been obvious. ;-) )

Comment: @DevSolar: I think the most appropriate translation is "annexed".

Comment: @DavidFoerster: That is what happened *de facto*, no doubt. The German word however carries an undertone ("Heim ins Reich") that isn't covered by "annexed". There *isn't* a really good translation including that undertone; indeed the Englisch version of the WP article [Anschluss Österreichs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss_%C3%96sterreichs) is also titled [Anschluss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss)... but you're right, *annexed* is better than *affiliated*, which carries an even stronger degree of voluntariness than "Anschluss", inappropriate in the context of the Sudetenland.

Comment: @DevSolar: "to annex" literally means "to join" or "to attach" or "to incorporate". If you don't like the connotation of the former maybe you can use one of the latter two. At least to me they sound still better than "to affiliate" here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Ah... you see, in German, "annektieren" means, very specifically, "incorporating *by force*". I didn't like "annex" for the exact opposide reason you named, as "Anschluss" implies some degree of voluntariness and "setting right". I don't agree with that implication, but wanted to stay as close to the original wording as possible as words are a touchy thing when it comes to history.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Elaborating on the meaning of "annex" vs. "annektieren"... you say it doesn't imply "by force" in English? For my understanding, Israel *annexed* the Golan Heights, but the FRG did *not* annex the territories of the former GDR (as that was done by voluntary treaty, not by force)...?

Comment: @DevSolar: Then what about "to incorporate"? That's pretty neutral and doesn't imply that the incorporated "body" did so voluntarily.

Comment: @DevSolar "Annex", the english word, does not necessarily mean it was done by force. It could be either way (tho most often it is done after warfare). The West Germany - East Germany re-unification is not a good example because those were roughly equal in size merging together. A good example would be a large country annexing a much smaller one on a voluntary basis. Off the top of my head, I can only think of one example: USSR annexing Tannu Tuva, tho I'm not sure how voluntary that was. Possibly North and South Yemen.

Comment: BTW, there's a question about this here: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/32840/were-there-occasions-when-a-sovereign-country-voluntarily-joined-another-country

Comment: @DevSolar In English, annex imply it was done without permission from the legitimate owner, though not necessarily by force. The reason the ascension of the five eastern states into the FDR isn't usually described as an annexation, is because it was regarded as a *re-unification*. Likewise, the Union of Castille with Aragon, of Scotland and England, or Denmark, Norway and Sweden are not usually called annexations. Conversely, you can find many references to the United States annexing Texas, or Britain annexing India, or Italy annexing Ethiopia. Size is irrelevant.